# Stress testing Apache using python

Tags: python, apache, python-3.x

Everyone,

I'm trying to stress test my apache server and below is what I wrote for this purpose (Not sure if this would do what I want to do)

```
import requests

url = "http://<ip of my server>"
response = requests.get(url,verify=False, json={})
sum = 0

while sum != 1:
    print (response.status_code)
```

I believe that the above code sends continuous get requests to my apache web server, which could put some stress on my server.

Not sure if I'm making sense with this.

Any directions on how can I put some stress on my apache would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For stress testing a Web app with Python, Molotov is - perhaps - your best friend.

https://molotov.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: thank you for your time. So the code that I have above would not help?

Comment: You need to change it slightly such it can be executed by a `@scenario`  decorated function that receives a `session` object. Please read the manual. Ah, BTW, your code as-is will go into an infinite loop that does... nothing ;)